# How to replace dots with commas in array by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array in single column in Google Sheets. the array contains dots "." as separator for fractional part (0.234, 23.6789, 34.987, etc.). I want to replace all dots in array with commas "," to get (0,234, 23,6789, 34,987, etc.) by Google Script.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work.

```
function checkItNow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TESTSCRIPTS');
  let vals1 = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().map(a => a[0]);
  Logger.log(vals1);
  let newVals1 = vals1.map(dots => dots.replace('.', ','));
```

#### DEMO:

```js
let vals1 = [0.234, 23.6789, 34.987]
let newVals1 = vals1.map(dots => dots.replace('.', ','));
console.log( newVals1 )
```

I get the error:

> Error: dots.replace is not a function

Where am I wrong and how to fix it?

My console log:

```
[20-03-27 15:16:29:211 ICT] [32.6942782575, 19.9155757705, 147.12263620000002, 489.1165073995, 892.202845, 0.37799999999999995, 0.023364250000000003, 0.26248482500000003, 0.15887690000000002, 23.026564925, 0.04906492500000001, 0.0, 706.7257752500001, 0.0, 0.0, 60.44003225000001, 0.0, 4.630720500000001, 618.5996974999999, 7.784899025, 108.97249249999999, 701.2664050000001, 1737.10503, 575.4707025, 3.8459734249999995, 0.6364439825, 0.456, 1.0932774250000001, 64.57385624999999, 23628.313777499996, 268.75, 1407.9519174999998, 8320.3449425, 10634.185062499999, 3.78603115, 6.715, 0.0, 6.715, 3.8336425000000003, 0.0, 4516.750427499999, 44.659411000000006, 1.1592136175, 1.7699011725000002, 8.076147557499999, 3.6708841524999993, 0.4781239375, 281.6134775, 2.4034999999999997, 219.05541475, 194.3, 10.0378800575]
```

Comment: Can you share what `vals1` here looks like? Is it an array of strings or numbers?

Comment: I edited with log of vals1

Comment: array vals1 looks like not strings

Comment: Errors are important and should be quoted in the question. Runnable demo should also be provided by simulating array values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this issue by using the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method:

```
let newVals1 = vals1.map(dots => dots.toString().replace(/\./g,','));
```

as `dots` here is actually a number and not a string and [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method works only on strings.

```js
let vals1 = [0.234, 23.6789, 34.987]
let newVals1 = vals1.map(dots => dots.toString().replace('.', ','));
console.log( newVals1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be like: `/\./g`

```js
let regex = /\./g

let vals1 = ['0.234', '23.6789', '34.987']
let newVals1 = vals1.map(dots => dots.replace(regex, '\,'));
console.log( newVals1 )
```

Comment: sorry. It doesn't work. Error: dots.replace is not a function

Comment: What you mean? The snippet is running without any issues. I just copied your code snippet then updated it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use

```
.replace(/\./g,',')
```

Comment: Why is this solution better? As far as I can tell this would replace everything with a ','. Since // introduces an Regex and . matches everything? The global flag would replace every character or did I miss something?

Comment: Why don't you try it. I use this in my projects and works nicely.

Comment: "foo bar".replace(/./g,',')
returns ",,,,,,,"

Comment: Isn't that the same as what OP is doing? What difference does it make and why does this answer the question?

Comment: sorry, guys. It doesn't work. Error: dots.replace is not a function